# asp.net textfield text property won't set

Tags: asp.net, textfield

I have the following function and a label and I want to set the label as abc.

```
<asp:Label ID="title" runat="server"></asp:Label>

protected void setTitle()
        {
            title.Text = "abc";
        }
```

When i execute the function, at the association line I get this:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Does somebody knows why?

LATER EDIT: see my comment below

I found this recommendation and it's still not working. It throws the same exception. Why?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
        }

        void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setTitle();
        }
```

Complete aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="......." CodeBehind="....aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left"><img src="Imagini/Left_01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="left_edge"><img src="Imagini/LeftEdge.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="questions">
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <h1>
                    <asp:Label ID="title" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right_edge"><img src="Imagini/rightedge_04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </form>
    <div id="right"><img src="Imagini/right_05.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try giving the Text="" in the UI.

Comment: Are you sure this exception is coming in these lines? Are we using some other variable or class that is not initialized?

Comment: If I comment that line, the page loads correctly and it's working properly.

Comment: Please update the code and show how you are calling the function in page load, also use try catch.

Comment: I think this problem appears because I call the method in the page_load. I read about it and I need to find a workaround to set that title when the page is completely loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: This is asp.net, not classic asp

Comment: @tzortzik Show your full markup (.aspx) you probably have that Label inside a Repeater/Grid or something like that. When done please use `@` to reply.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I updated my first post

Comment: @tzortzik cheers, can't see anything wrong just yet. Are you sure the `setTitle()` method is inside the code behind file defined in the `<%@ Page ` directive? Do you see the label with Visual Studio intellisense?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's ok. If a make a reference to title label, it is pointing ok. And also it's pointing well to the other elements of the page which are radio buttons and textareas

Comment: @tzortzik sorry, so I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The only problem I have here is that I cannot set the text for that label in the way I explained at the top of the page

Comment: But you said "if a make a reference to title label, it is pointing ok" - so what you mean by that?

Comment: From where do you call SetTitle() ???

Comment: @ShadowWizard If I write: title.T it the editor will show me title.Text and I can select it.

Comment: @FlopScientist I am calling setTitle when the page is loaded

Comment: Tried your above code and it works for me. Any stack trace you can show??

Comment: Try clearing the ASP.NET temporary files and make sure to also Rebuild the Visual Studio Solution.